# How to access to local variable from outside the function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to access to local variable from outside the function ?

When pressed, it should alert `distance_bottom` value, but it's not working, how can I make it work?

http://jsfiddle.net/dyjb8r9w/11/

```
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
(function() {    
    var mY, distance_bottom,
        $distance_bottom = $('#distance_bottom span'),
        $element_bottom  = $('#element_bottom');

    function calculatedistance_bottom(elem , mouseY) {
        return Math.floor(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mouseY - (elem.offset().top+(elem.height()/2)), 2)));
    }

    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {        
        mY = e.pageY;
        distance_bottom = calculatedistance_bottom($element_bottom , mY);
        $distance_bottom.text(distance_bottom);
    });
})();
});
</script>





<script>
function reply_click()
{    
    alert(distance_bottom);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Simple answer: Don't make it local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it global by prefixing it with `window.` and removing it from the variable declaration at the top. The below line did the trick

```
window.distance_bottom = calculatedistance_bottom($element_bottom , mY);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dyjb8r9w/12/)

Comment: yes, i try for 5 time to mark answer , but i must wait for 5 minute.

Comment: Of course the variable is not local anymore. It's impossible to access a *local* variable outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it you have two options, first one implies changing the function and the other one doesn't:

1- make that a global variable by not declaring it inside the function with var

2- Access the value on the HTML using javascript/jQuery.

Ex: alert($('#distance_bottom span').html());

(Example in jQuery for simplicity)

Comment: Yes, Answer edited. Personally I don't like to declare variables in the window/global scope but that's up to you

Comment: Why you don't like to declare variables  ?